# Rebuilding object files with Makefile

Tags: makefile

Is there any way to cause a certain target to be rebuilt based on the value of a variable?

I have a Makefile with a command-line setting called DEBUG. I want certain object files to be rebuilt (to contain debug information) when I call "make DEBUG=yes" after haveing executed "make DEBUG=no".

Comment: Just to be clear, you want Make's behavior to depend not just on the variable (which is easy) but on the way it was run before (which is trickier). And I'm guessing you want to have two different versions of an object file (regular and `DEBUG`), but you want them to have the same name and reside in the same directory, so that only one of them can exist at a time. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Write the value of that variable into a file if the file doesn't exist or if it has a different value. Make all your object files depend on that file, so that whenever the file changes all object files get recompiled. E.g.:

```
BUILD := debug
SHELL := /bin/bash
$(shell [[ `cat .build 2>/dev/null` == ${BUILD} ]] || echo ${BUILD} > .build)

all : prog

prog : .build
    touch $@

clean :
    rm prog .build

.PHONY: all clean
```

Example run:

```
$ make
touch prog
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
$ make BUILD=release
touch prog
$ make BUILD=release
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

A better way is to build debug and release builds into different directories like MSVS does, but that requires a bit more advanced makefiles.

Comment: I´m working on a very restricted Windows environment, so I don't have all the GNU goodies (cat, echo, etc). Any ideas?

Comment: Then use whatever scripting is available to you.

Comment: I don't think windows shell features operators like [[]] or ||. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can use a vb, javascript or a python script for that.